# Prestashop Real Quantity Different From Physical Quantity

Tags: php, mysql, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

In mine Prestdashop 1.6.1.9 I set up the POS and the e-commerce for selling in our shop and online.

In the last few days I saw an error inside the shop:

- The real quantity is lower then the physical
- the physical is negative in some product
- if someone buy a 0 product, sometimes it can go in negative status

I have tried all the solutions of the prestashop forum and I've blocked the negative sell in any position however without success.

There's a chance to reset some quantity via Database or a code for prevent prestashop to go in negative?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can create a mysql trigger when the stocks is update/insert

example:

```
CREATE TRIGGER ins_transaction BEFORE INSERT ON account
       FOR EACH ROW PRECEDES ins_sum
       SET
       @deposits = @deposits + IF(NEW.amount>0,NEW.amount,0),
       @withdrawals = @withdrawals + IF(NEW.amount<0,-NEW.amount,0);
```

You can add some similar and if the quantity is less 0, update the row.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html

-EDIT-

Also you can try to change the functions `updateQuantity() and setQuantity()` in the class StockAvailable

try add some like:

```
 if($delta_quantity<0)
    $delta_quantity=0;
```

hope it help you

Answer (score 0):

From the question I think the problem is negative quantity.

There is two places in prestashop's backoffice that you can set this behavior:

- General for all products: Preferences -> Products ("Products Stock" section)
- Product Specific: Catalog -> Products (Choose a product) ("Quantities" section)

In addition to setting the right choice in General settings, you should check for each product in its specific settings to see if it has overridden the general settings.

Answer (score 0):

There is another way to have get the perfect one.

I got this error from the ORDER STATUS bar and the Cancelled Order.

When you cancel and order, this one still have product inside. You must remove all the product from the order then cancel it.

Another way it's on the order status:

You need to sign it as Shipped and and Validate!

Hope this can help :D